# Column values to header oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I have a table with  schema as below

```
Empid   Field Type  Field Value
123         Name          John
123         Age            33
124         Name          Tijo
124         Age            24
```

Output should be in followinf format

```
Empid       Name             Age
123         John             33
124         Tijo             24
```

How can i implement this using query from oracle database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to `PIVOT` your table.  One option is to use `MAX` with `CASE`:

```
select empid,
   max(case when fieldtype = 'Name' then fieldvalue end) Name,
   max(case when fieldtype = 'Age' then fieldvalue end) Age
from yourtable
group by empid
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/08b81/1)

Comment: @JijilPK -- np, glad we could help!

Answer (score 6):

This type of transformation of rows into columns is known as a PIVOT.  There are several ways that this can be done.

Since you are using Oracle 11g, you can use the PIVOT function:

```
select empid, Name, age
from
(
  select empid,
    fieldtype,
    fieldvalue
  from yt
) 
pivot
(
  max(fieldvalue)
  for fieldtype in ('Name' as Name, 'Age' as Age)
);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c0db/3).

Prior to Oracle 11g, you could use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select empid,
  max(case when fieldtype = 'Name' then fieldvalue end) name,
  max(case when fieldtype = 'Age' then fieldvalue end) age
from yt
group by empid;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c0db/4).

You can also get the result by joining on the table multiple times:

```
select t1.empid,
  t1.fieldvalue name,
  t2.fieldvalue age
from yt t1
left join yt t2
  on t1.empid = t2.empid
  and t2.fieldtype = 'Age'
where t1.fieldtype = 'Name';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3c0db/5).  Each version gives the result:

```
| EMPID | NAME | AGE |
----------------------
|   123 | John |  33 |
|   124 | Tijo |  24 |
```

Comment: The last approach will only work assuming the "Name" exists in the Field Type for each employee id (it does with the sample data).  Might be safer introducing a third join for the last option.  Nice use of PIVOT though (as always)!

Comment: @sgeddes I assumed every record will have a `name`. :)